# Flutter How can I show value of array from a array

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter how can i show the array data of array.

My data looks like this

```
I/flutter ( 7557): {count: 1, 
records: [{
 cnic: 42501-0978008-5,
 name: abc 
 family_members: [{
  gender: F, 
  name: Dua Batool, 
  age: 8, 
  relationship: Daughter
}, 
{
  gender: M, 
  name: Shayan, 
  age: 9, 
  relationship: Son
}
]}]}
```

What I need to do is I need to print the name of Family members array.

My code is this

```
 Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_company_employee.php?offset=0&limit=1&cnic=${value}' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var Data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Data);
  }
```

Its printing Data value ,as I show you on the upper side of question, I need to print the Family members name. I know its stupid question but I am not able to print the name of the Familymembers array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_company_employee.php?offset=0&limit=1&cnic=${value}' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data);

    var familyMembers = data["records"][0]["familyMembers"]
    print(familyMembers);
    for (var familyMember in familyMembers){ //prints the name of each family member
            var familyMemberName = familyMember["name"];
            print(familyMemberName);
  }
```

If you have multiple items in your records list, you can use a loop and print each familyMember:

```
Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_company_employee.php?offset=0&limit=1&cnic=${value}' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data);
    var recordsList = data["records"];
    for (var record in recordsList){
        var familyMembers = record["familyMembers"]
        print(familyMembers);
        for (var familyMember in familyMembers){ //prints the name of each family member
            var familyMemberName = familyMember["name"];
            print(familyMemberName);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much first one is working fine. Can you tell one more thing how can I show these name in Text widget ?

Comment: you're welcome. you can create a list inside your function and add the family members name to it. then return the list and  use the items of the returned value as you Text widget value. I don't know how you want to show them but if you want to show all of them, use a ListView widget with the returned list

Comment: use FutureBuilder

Comment: yes you can also use a FutureBuilder and return a Text widget from its builder method

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to be feeling silly bout. We are here to learn. For answering your question, I am using [forEach()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map_function_foreach.htm). What it does is, it iterates over your data, and get the value from the array

Your code is this much only

```dart
  // mapping your records array
  Data['records'].forEach((item){
    // mapping your family_members array
    item['family_members'].forEach((nestedItem){
      print(nestedItem['name']);
    });
  });
```

Let us show this in your dart code method. You would get more idea

```
void main() {
  Map data = {
  'count': 1, 
  'records': [
    {
      'cnic': 42501-0978008-5,
      'name': 'abc' ,
      'family_members': [
        {
          'gender': 'F', 
          'name': 'Dua Batool', 
          'age': 8, 
          'relationship': 'Daughter'
        }, 
        {
          'gender': 'M', 
          'name': 'Shayan', 
          'age': 9, 
          'relationship': 'Son'
        }
      ]
    }           
  ]};
  
  // mapping your records array
  data['records'].forEach((item){
    // mapping your family_members array
    item['family_members'].forEach((nestedItem){
      print(nestedItem['name']);
    });
  });
  
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Dua Batool
Shayan
```